# How can I get the index ranges of a pandas series that are NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in Pandas where the indices are dates and the columns are codes, like this:
[image]

I need to identify the columns that have NaN values, I implemented this part like this:

```
boundaries_with_incomplete_days = boundaries.columns[
            boundaries.isna().any()
        ].to_list()
```

So, boundaries_with_incomplete_days is a list where I have the codes (columns containing NaN values). The problem is that now I need to identify the date ranges in which there are NaN values. For example, for frt00338:
From 2024-01-03 2:00:00 to 2024-01-03 8:00:00,
From 2024-01-07 2:00:00 to 2024-01-07 12:00:00
The way I get this is irrelevant, it could be a list of tuples for example:

```
[("2024-01-03 2:00:00", "2024-01-03 8:00:00"), ("2024-01-07 2:00:00", "2024-01-07 12 :00:00")]
```

My idea is to iterate over boundaries_with_incomplete_days, and identify those ranges for each code, however I'm not sure how I could efficiently find these ranges, I wouldn't want to have to loop over all the data for each code. How could I implement it?

Comment: This wouldn't get a range, but you can get all indices that haver a NaN somewhere in its row with `df.index[df.isna().any(axis = 1))`.

Comment: The problem is that the client wants the ranges. It is to create a log that the user can see in the application, so it would be a very long log in the graphical interface to show all the indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
out = {}
for col in boundaries.columns[boundaries.isna().any()]:
    # locate nan values
    m = boundaries[col].notna()

    # create groups from consecutive nan
    g = m.cumsum().mask(m)

    # extract range (first and last dates from the group)
    r = boundaries.index.to_series().groupby(g).agg(['min', 'max']).astype(str)

    # export result
    out[col] = list(zip(*r.to_dict('list').values()))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
{'frt00338': [('2024-01-03 02:00:00', '2024-01-03 08:00:00'),
  ('2024-01-07 02:00:00', '2024-01-07 12:00:00')]}
```

> I wouldn't want to have to loop over all the data for each code

Even though it's a loop, the code inside the loop is vectorized, so this shouldn't be a problem.